# VS Code GitLens path using or single backslashes

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64, gitlens

Ive reinstalled my PC (Windows) and now the following functionality that worked completely fine doesnt anymore:

e.g. Deleting a branch with the gitlens plugin:

1. have a local git branch in the currently active repository
2. navigate to "Branches" tab of gitlens (under "source control")
3. right click onthe branch -> "Delete Branch..." -> Delete Branch
4. PROBLEM: the path to the git executable is done via single backslashes which windows cant handle:

```
myusername@mypc MINGW64 /c/projects/project (another_branch)
$ C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe -C "c:/projects/project" -c "core.editor=code --wait --reuse-window" branch --delete "branch-i-want-to-delete"
bash: C:UsersmyusernameAppDataLocalProgramsGitcmdgit.exe: command not found
```

Comment: you are using the wrong terminal, bash uses `/` as a separator

Comment: why don't you type `git branch -D branchename` in the terminal

Comment: i know that bash uses forward slash and also that I can delete it "by hand" via the command, but this is both not my problem/question. It worked exactly like this before and I want to regain that functionality.